# Show comment author e-mail in comment.html.twig

Tags: 8, theming, comments

Anonymous users can leave their e-mail when posting a comment but how can I display this e-mail as a plain text value in the comment.html.twig?

Comment: By default, anonymous comments have no such "e-mail" field. Was this field added by you?

Comment: If yes and you used the e-mail field type, then simply go to the comments manage display and for Format select plain text.

Comment: You can enable anonymous users to leave their contact information in the comments field of a content type.

Comment: Where is that option located at?

Comment: If you have a fresh Drupal 8 standard install, go to: 'People > Permissions' and Allow anonymous users to 'Post comments' and 'Skip comment approval'. Then go to: 'Structure > Content Types > Article > Manage Fields'  and edit the 'Comments' field. Go to 'Anonymous commenting' and select 'Anonymous posters may leave their contact information'. Click 'Save settings'. Now when you go post a comment as an anonymous user you can leave your e-mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you have a fresh Drupal 8 standard install, go to: 'People >
>   Permissions' and Allow anonymous users to 'Post comments' and 'Skip
>   comment approval'. Then go to: 'Structure > Content Types > Article >
>   Manage Fields' and edit the 'Comments' field. Go to 'Anonymous
>   commenting' and select 'Anonymous posters may leave their contact
>   information'. Click 'Save settings'. Now when you go post a comment as
>   an anonymous user you can leave your e-mail.

You can print that e-mail value in plain text like this:

```
{{ content.comment_body['#object'].getAuthorEmail() }}
```

Now, this will print the e-mails of logged in users as well. If you don't want that, then you will need to add a conditional to check if their User ID is 0, which means they are anonymous.

```
{% if attributes.toArray()['data-comment-user-id'] == 0 %}

    {{ content.comment_body['#object'].getAuthorEmail() }}

{% endif %}
```