# How to automatically populate a field with a value part of another field

Tags: 8, entities

I will try to be as specific as possible.

I have a required text plain field in a content type, say 'field_A'.  This will have values of minimum 2 words, maximum 5 words. **Words will be separated by spaces**.  I can be certain of this.

What I want, is to have another field, say 'field_B' in which I want to keep the **last word of field_A**.  I would like this to happen automatically (upon creation of a node of this type).

I have no idea if this is possible ...

So, say I 'm adding new content of this type, and use value "lorem ipsum whatever" for field_A, upon submitting I would like the word 'whatever' to be inserted as a value in field_B.

I 'd be grateful of any help ..  I couldn't find relevant info on this, it's kinda hard to describe in a few words.

Working on D8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need a custom module for this.

Add  `MODULENAME` directory inside your `modules` directory.  Inside the directroy create file `MODULENAME.info.yml` with contents:

```
name: Last word copy
description: 'gets last word from field_a and saves it to field_b'
core: 8.x
type: module
package: COMPANYNAME
dependencies:
  - node
```

This module implements `hook_form_alter` that will make *field_b* readonly / disabled and `hook_entity_presave` which will get the last word added to `field_b` upon save or update of a node of *CONTENTTYPE*

Create also `MODULENAME.module` file with contents:

```
<?php
function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 
  if(in_array($form_id,['node_CONTENTTYPE_form','node_CONTENTTYPE_edit_form'])) {
    $form['field_b']['#disabled'] = 'disabled';
  }   
} 

function MODULENAME_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {  
  if($entity->bundle() == "CONTENTTYPE"){    
    $pieces = explode(' ', $entity->field_a->value);
    $last_word = array_pop($pieces);
    $entity->field_b->value = $last_word;
    //save is done automatically
  }  
}
```

You NEED to replace *MODULENAME* and *CONTENTTYPE* in the above code.

If all is correct go to *Extend* (admin/modules) and enable the module.

Comment: thanks a lot for your info. I haven't created any custom modules yet - I 'm fairly new to drupal. But I will look into that. I thought it might be possible through preprocess functions, or any other (fairly simple) way. But still, your contribution is invaluable.

Comment: Added more specific instructions on how to create this module

Comment: It does work my friend. I just tried it. Really helpful, and very well explained and given. Thanks a lot. I will research these hook functions, they can clearly be extremely useful .. If you can point to any good starting point for documentation and/or tutorials, please do.

Comment: You can start with this http://befused.com/drupal/first-drupal8-module or this https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules or ask specific questions here or dig into a simple module to see how things are done or study the api to see what is possible https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api and try to build a site there is always going to be questions and opportunities to learn.

Comment: In Drupal 8 You can exclude the form_alter() hook and just remove the field from the form display in the UI under Manage form display for the entity type.

Comment: @sonfd yes true but that would also depend on the use case ...

Comment: Any clues how to modify it for when 'field_A' is not actually a field, but the node's label? It is accessible for example in the template via node.label. However, I get an error with the custom module, 'Trying to get property of non-object in XXXX_entity_presave()' when I tried with: '$pieces = explode(' ', $entity->label->value);' ... Any clues? Is the label accessible there? And what type would it be? ...

Comment: title/label has special way to get the value `$entity->label()` ... perhaps you should spend some time setting up a development environment for yourself https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/259037/what-is-easiest-way-to-debug-variables-in-nodes-views-blocks-and-page-twig-tem/259108