# How to get height and width of image style?

Tags: 8, media

We have a custom module `mymodule` where we call `mymodule_tokens` so that we can assign custom token values from the current node. These custom tokens are used to insert values in the Article's MetaTag fields.

**Problem**

When fetching the default value based on an Image Style (e.g. medium), I cannot get the Height and Width based on the Configuration for the Image Style. How can I get the height and width from the Image Style?

**What I have tried, but cannot get the height and width:**

```
function mymodule_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data, array $options, \Drupal\Core\Render\BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata) {
  $replacements = [];
  $node = $data['node'];
  $node_image = $node->field_image;
  $field_image_style = 'medium';

  if($node_image->isEmpty()) {
    $field_info = FieldConfig::loadByName('node', 'article, 'field_image');
    $image_uuid = $field_info->getSetting('default_image')['uuid'];
    $image = Drupal::service('entity.repository')->loadEntityByUuid('file', $image_uuid);
    $field_image_url = ImageStyle::load($field_image_style)->buildUrl($image->getFileUri());
    $image_style = ImageStyle::load($field_image_style)->getEffects()->getConfiguration();

    // Both give me error messages.
    $image_style_height = $image_style->get('height');
    $image_style_width = $image_style->get('width');
  }
  else {
    $field_image_url = $node_field_image->entity->getFileUri();
    $image_style = ImageStyle::load($field_image_style)->getEffects()->getConfiguration();

    // Both give me error messages.
    $image_style_height = $image_style->get('height');
    $image_style_width = $image_style->get('width');
  }

  foreach($tokens as $name => $original) {
    switch ($name) {
      case 'custom_image_url':
        $replacements[$original] = $field_image_url;
        break;
      case 'custom_image_height':
        $replacements[$original] = $image_style_height;
        break;
      case 'custom_image_width':
        $replacements[$original] = $image_style_width;
       break;
    }
  }    

  return $replacements;
}
```

**Error Message**

> Error: Call to a member function get() on array in mymodule_tokens()

**When printing `ImageStyle::load($field_image_style)` using Kint this is what we get.**

[image: image style array]

**When printing `$image_style`, I get the following.**

[image: image_style]

**Using core or contrib tokens rather than custom tokens**

Using the following tokens only work when there is a value added to the `field_image` field, but when the `field_image` is not populated, the token is not able to return the default image that is populated on the field's settings page.

```
[node:field_image:medium:height]
[node:field_image:medium:url]
[node:field_image:medium:width]
```

Comment: Have you installed the Devel sub-module Kint and then did `ksm($image_style)` to show you the available methods? I doubt that the `$image_style` object holds the finalized image properties.

Comment: @leymannx i have updated the question with screenshots using `kint()` (same output when using `ksm()`). I can see that in the `'data'` array the width and height are there. I wonder if it has to do with being protected.

Comment: Everything under "image_scale_and_crop" is protected, so you won't be able to read those values. What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: @Kevin The Image Style `medium` performs a scale and crop where `width => 400` and `height => 260`. I wanted to query that setting and use it to assign values to the custom tokens (see updated code) rather than hard coding the `400` and `260` in case those values are changed. Tokens such as `[node:field_image:medium:height]` does not return a value when the `field_image` is empty, hence the custom tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to click on the Available Methods tab and see if there is an method for width and height.

[image]

When you click on it, searching for width or height should come up empty. I can tell this by looking at the [ImageStyle Class](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21image%21src%21Entity%21ImageStyle.php/class/ImageStyle/8.2.x).

But there will be a `getEffects()` method that you can use, which should contain the width and height.

```
$style = ImageStyle::load($field_image_style);
```

So do `kint($style->getEffects());`

I'll let you take it from here.

---

If you want to go the `$image_style` route then you can get the value with

```
$image_style[0]['1aa.......']['data']['width'];
$image_style[0]['1aa.......']['data']['height'];
```

**PS:**

I suggest you read my answer to [What is easiest way to debug variables in nodes, views, blocks and page twig templates?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/259037/what-is-easiest-way-to-debug-variables-in-nodes-views-blocks-and-page-twig-tem/259108#259108) to learn how to use kint properly.

Comment: If you see my answer below, i was able to iterate through it in a loop using the answer you provided.

Answer (score 8):

If you wonder how to get the height/width of a rendered image style (not Image style configuration, but the result itself), here's how it's done :

```
<?php
use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;

$img_uri = $entity->field_picture->entity->getFileUri();
$image_style = ImageStyle::load('your_image_style');
// $build_url = $image_style->buildUrl($img_uri);
$build_uri = $image_style->buildUri($img_uri);
$image_factory = \Drupal::service('image.factory')->get($build_uri);

$height = $image_factory->getToolkit()->getHeight();
$width = $image_factory->getToolkit()->getWidth();
```

Comment: This is great. But .. If the image has not been generated beforehand, the $height and $width are 0 / 0 (because the styled image does not actually exist). This does create the correct URL, but the image is not generated until the path is visited.

Comment: You can check if the image has been generated with `file_exists($build_uri)`. `$image_style->createDerivative($img_uri, $build_uri)` will create the derivative file.

Answer (score 4):

No Sssweat's answer inspired this.

I added this before if statement (`if($node_image->isEmpty())`) to get the height and width.

```
$image_style_config = (ImageStyle::load('medium')->getEffects()->getConfiguration());

foreach($image_style_config as $config) { 
  if(isset($config['data'])) {
    if(isset($config['data']['height'])) {
      $image_style_height = $config['data']['height'];
    }
    if(isset($config['data']['width'])) {
      $image_style_width = $config['data']['width'];
    }
  }
}
```