# How to print the file description to my twig template?

Tags: 8, theming, entities

I'm trying to figure how I can obtain or print the file description that is uploaded on my node and display on my twig template

So far I have tried `{{ file.entity.label }}` which only prints the name of the file. I even tried `{{ file.entity.value }}` or `{{ file.entity.title }}`.

Here is a sample of the code I have been working on

```
{% for file in object.entity.field_file %}

    <li>{{ file.entity.label }}  {{ file_url(file.entity.uri.value) }}</li>

{% endfor %}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Rather than playing the guessing game, how about debugging it? Get good, [A: What is easiest way to debug variables in nodes, views, blocks and page twig templates?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/259037/what-is-easiest-way-to-debug-variables-in-nodes-views-blocks-and-page-twig-tem/259108#259108)

Comment: Already did tried using kint to debug the issue. Managed to search and look at the table in order for me to fetch the values but It seems I'm doing it incorrectly. I tried to fetch it using the following code `{{ item.entity.description.value }}`

Comment: What template are you currently in?

Comment: @leymannx `page.html.twig`

Comment: Really, `page.html.twig` shouldn't be the template to print field content like that. A new custom field formatter would be the way to go. But nevertheless what makes me really wonder is why as in your screenshot the description seems to be just empty `""`.

Comment: @leymannx are you referring to this screenshot?  imgur.com/a/EdzgGe7

Comment: Yep, or the one above.

Comment: @leymannx, I'm still wondering about that, even though the field description has a value inside of it

Comment: @clestcruz I don't see your .doc file there either. You should be using node--[content-type].html.twig

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `node` variable is available in both `page.html.twig` and `node.html.twig`, so you can get your file description with

```
{% for file in node.field_myfile %}
  {{ file.description }}
{% endfor %}
```

Replace `field_myfile` with the machine name of your file field.

Comment: this is not working for me, but another thing works
`{{ file._referringItem.description }}`