# Order receipt mail -> shipping_information variable

Tags: commerce

How can I output the individual information of the variable shipping_information in a template file? For the *billing_information* variable, I followed [How can I get the customer name in an order confirmation e-mail?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263652/how-to-get-the-customer-name-in-commerce-order-confirmation-e-mail) but that doesn't work in my case.

---

Hello,

thanks for your answer. I use this template file :

```
commerce-order-receipt.html.twig
```

In my estore.theme file i use this code for the billing information, witch works :

```
function estore_preprocess_commerce_order_receipt(&$vars)
{
      # BillingAddress
      $vars['billing_organization']   = $vars['billing_information']['#profile']->get('address')[0]->organization;
      $vars['billing_given_name']     = $vars['billing_information']['#profile']->get('address')[0]->given_name;
      $vars['billing_family_name']    = $vars['billing_information']['#profile']->get('address')[0]->family_name;
      $vars['billing_address_line1']  = $vars['billing_information']['#profile']->get('address')[0]->address_line1;
      $vars['billing_address_line2']  = $vars['billing_information']['#profile']->get('address')[0]->address_line2;
      $vars['billing_postal_code']    = $vars['billing_information']['#profile']->get('address')[0]->postal_code;
      $vars['billing_locality']       = $vars['billing_information']['#profile']->get('address')[0]->locality;
      $billing_country_code           = $vars['billing_information']['#profile']->get('address')[0]->country_code;
      $billing_lang_code              = $vars['billing_information']['#profile']->get('address')[0]->langcode;
      $billing_countries              = CountryManager::getStandardList();
      $vars['billing_country']        = t($billing_countries[$billing_country_code]->__toString());
      #$vars['billing_country']        = t($billing_countries[$billing_country_code]->getUntranslatedString(), [], ['langcode' => $billing_lang_code ]);
    }
```

And now I want to extend this function so that I get all the information of the variable *shipping_information* individually, like with the variable *billing_information*. But

```
$vars['shipping_given_name']     = $vars['shipping_information']['#profile']->get('address')[0]->given_name;
```

dont work.

Regards Maik

Comment: Please be more specific and tell us which template file. Also, adding the exact code that you tried is helpful for us. Hopefully you renamed the `hook` part to your actual module name and put the code in a .module file.

Comment: Hi. I added the information in my question above. Regards Maik