# Problems with altering a form

Tags: 8, forms, hooks

I'm wanting to alter the commerce cart page form.

By using `var_dump($form_id)` or chrome inspect I can see the id is `id="views-form-commerce-cart-form-orange-default-42"`. If I write my hook as :

```
function module_form_views_form_commerce_cart_form_orange_default_42_alter
```

I can see that I am altering the form. But this has been altered in my theme hence the extra bit on the id `orange_default_42`. If I do :

```
function testingstuffs_form_views_form_commerce_cart_form_alter
```

I cannot alter the form.

How do I hook into this form correctly / is there  a correct way to find form ids?

Comment: @NoSssweat I had seen that. `print_r` always crashes my site. Through chrome devtools works and is how I found this. What I'm wondering is if I can alter this without the extra orange chunk on there as that's from the theme.

Comment: Install the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module and enable Kint and then you can do `kint($form_id);`. For more info on how to use kint, [see this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/259108/27710).

Comment: `I'm wondering is if I can alter this without the extra orange chunk` The only way might be by using [hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/8.2.x). You'll need to `kint($form);` or `kint($form_state)`, I forgot which one, to see if it has a base form ID.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that there are probably two form IDs for the form. One is the `form_id`, and the lesser known one is the `base_form_id`. If a Drupal form is used more than once on a page, weird things come about. To get around this, form developers can set the form ID to be dynamic, so that each time the form is built, it's given a unique ID. Example:

```
class FooBarForm implements FormInterface {

  protected $id;

  public function __construct($type) {
    $this->id = $id;
  }

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'foo_bar_form-' . $this->id;
  }
}

class FooRouteController {

  public function fooBarForm(ContentEntityInterface $entity) {
    $form = new FooBarForm($entity->id());

    return \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($form);
  }
}
```

Forms can also implement [BaseFormIdInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21BaseFormIdInterface.php/interface/BaseFormIdInterface/8.8.x), which requires them to implement [BaseFormIdInterface::getBaseFormId()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21BaseFormIdInterface.php/function/BaseFormIdInterface%3A%3AgetBaseFormId/8.8.x). The form ID returned from this hook will be the same for all instances of the form, and NOT dynamic.

```
class FooBarForm implements FormInterface, BaseFormIdInterface {

  protected $id;

  public function __construct($type) {
    $this->id = $id;
  }

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'foo_bar_form-' . $this->id;
  }

  public function getBaseFormId() {
    return 'foo_bar_form';
  }
}
```

The relevance of this is that there are actually multiple form alter hooks called, in this order:

1. [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.8.x)
2. [hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/8.8.x)
3. [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.8.x)

Looking at your hook - `module_form_views_form_commerce_cart_form_orange_default_42_alter`, it would appear you are implementing the third hook. The ID of 42 is being appended as part of the dynamic Form ID.

To find out the base form ID (if one exists), you can call the following in your form:

`$form_state->getBuildInfo()`

This will give you the build info, which you can dump with `kint()` or however you do your debugging. In the build info will be the base form ID (assuming it's set). If it is, you can implement the second form alter hook above, using that base form ID.