# Get list of preprocess block variables

Tags: 8, blocks, hooks

How can I display a list of preprocess block variables so I can conditionally include a library? Using the 'plugin_id' doesn't seem to work and when I echo all of the variables all I see is a blank page. Is there a Drupal page that will show me what all the variables are for blocks?

My custom block module is called, 'leaflet_block'.

```
function leaflet_block_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  echo "<pre>"; print_r($variables); echo "</pre>"; // shows a blank page

  if ($variables['plugin_id'] == 'leaflet_block') {
    $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'leaflet_block/leaflet_block';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `echo "<pre>"; print_r($variables); echo "</pre>";`

That's not how it should be done, instead, install the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module.

This will allow you to do:

```
dump($variables);
```

If you haven't turned caching off, for developing purposes, then you will have to flush all caches to see the dump.

---

In addition, if you also install the kint package/library with:

```
composer require kint-php/kint
```

now you could also do:

```
kint($variables);
```

<sub>Related: [Welcome to Kint 101](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/259108/27710)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the help. After installing Devel I was able to dump the variables. I still wasn't able to access the module name/title, which is probably another questions, so I used '\Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();' to get the path and write a condition against that.